# Double Negation in Type Theory

Tags: propositional-calculus, type-theory

How do I derive a proof of double negation in type theory for *Exercise 1.11* of the book *HoTT*? That is a proof of type $(((A \rightarrow \textbf{0}) \rightarrow \textbf{0}) \rightarrow \textbf{0}) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow \textbf{0})$, where objects of type $\textbf{0}$ are contradictions.

Is this equivalent to proving $((A \rightarrow \textbf{0}) \rightarrow \textbf{0}) \rightarrow A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *not* equivalent to $((A \rightarrow \mathbf{0}) \rightarrow \mathbf{0}) \rightarrow A$; in fact, that statement (for arbitrary types $A$) is inconsistent in HoTT.

To prove $(((A \rightarrow \mathbf{0}) \rightarrow \mathbf{0}) \rightarrow \mathbf{0}) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow \mathbf{0})$ is by definition to provide a function from $((A \rightarrow \mathbf{0}) \rightarrow \mathbf{0}) \rightarrow \mathbf{0}$ and $A$ to $\mathbf{0}$—that is, a value of the form $\lambda f . \lambda a . …$.  What should go in place of the ellipses?  Well, we need a value of type $\mathbf{0}$, so it seems prudent to apply $f$ to something of type $(A \rightarrow \mathbf{0}) \rightarrow \mathbf{0}$.  In order to construct such a thing, it suffices to provide a value of the form $\lambda g . …$.  This second set of ellipses needs to be replaced with a value of type $\mathbf{0}$ again, but we now have access to $g : A \rightarrow \mathbf{0}$, so we can apply it to $a$ and we are completely done.  Consequently, a proof (and, I might add, the *intended* proof) of $(((A \rightarrow \mathbf{0}) \rightarrow \mathbf{0}) \rightarrow \mathbf{0}) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow \mathbf{0})$ is $\lambda f . \lambda a . f(\lambda g . g(a))$.

Comment: When you say, "to prove $(((A \rightarrow \mathbf{0}) \rightarrow \mathbf{0}) \rightarrow \mathbf{0}) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow \mathbf{0})$ is by definition to provide a function from $((A \rightarrow \mathbf{0}) \rightarrow \mathbf{0}) \rightarrow \mathbf{0}$ and $A$ to $\mathbf{0}$." Is this because $\rightarrow$ is right-associative?

Comment: @MoronicAcid Yes.  You can always transform a function of type $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C$ into one of type $A \times B \rightarrow C$, and vice versa; this is known as *currying*.